# How to change numerical precision in python?

Tags: python, precision

If I write 1e-15 in python, python can distinguish that number from zero but if I write 1e-16 python can not distinguish that number from 0. So python is precise up to 16th digit. Is there a way to reduce this precision to for example 10 digits? How? Can I make calculations with some

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have a look at the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) which has controllable precision.

Comment: Show some code. There shouldn't be any problem distinguishing 1e-16 from 0.

Comment: My guess is he is typing `>>> 1e-15` in the interpreter and seeing represented value printed and then typing `1e-16` in the interpreter and seeing `0.0` as the representation. The true test is something like `1e-256>0` and seeing `True` or `False` in this case. *Representation is not fact...*

Comment: If I type `1e-16` in the interpreter, I get `1e-16` back. It's not zero. That's in the latest CPython though.

Comment: @gilch: Depends on the version of the Python interpreter, but you will get `0.0` represented more quickly than Python's inability to deal with small numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want precise arithmetic in your computations, it is highly discouraged to use the default `float` type. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) section of the official documentation.

This is why you will be much better off with [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). It has several ways to control the precision.

Here we change the precision globally:

```py
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

And here we do it for a single number:

```py
>> Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429').quantize('0.01')
Decimal('0.14')
```

You can find more examples [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).